# Which event handler to use for ensureColumnVisible in ag-grid?

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid-angular

I wanted my ag-grid to be scrolled back to its original position after refresh which is not happening so I researched and found this ensureColumnVisible in grid api. Please help me finding the solution to it.

Event handler to be used for this ensureColumnVisible

Answer (score 0):

[This page](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/grid-events/) shows all of their available events. I guess I would suggest the [RowDataUpdatedEvent](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/grid-events/#reference-clientRowModel-rowDataUpdated), based off your brief description?

> The client has updated data for the grid by either a) setting new Row Data or b) Applying a Row Transaction.

Providing more detail always helps in providing a better answer; any details of things you've already tried, existing code snippets, etc. would help pinpoint more precisely what you want.